# Get all open search (point in time) in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

To create a new point a time we do

```
POST /my-index-000001/_pit?keep_alive=1m
```

output:

```
{
  "id": "46ToAwMDaWR5BXV1aWQyKwZub2RlXzMAAAAAAAAAACoBYwADaWR4BXV1aWQxAgZub2RlXzEAAAAAAAAAAAEBYQADaWR5BXV1aWQyKgZub2RlXzIgAAAAA=="
}
```

It will return a PIT ID.

Now to get the total number of open search, we do

```
GET /_nodes/stats/indices/search
```

and output has

```
"open_contexts" : 18,
```

As Elastic says that we should close/delete the PIT after the work is done. [Close the Point in time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html#close-point-in-time-api)

Now the question:

1. how can we get ids of all open search or PITs?
2. if we can not get the Ids, is there any way to close the search after a time or it is auto-closed after keep-alive time ended.

I am not able to find any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do retrieve the IDs of the opened search contexts, you're supposed to keep track of them in your application code.

As [the link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html#close-point-in-time-api) you provided states:

> Point-in-time is automatically closed when its keep_alive has been elapsed.

So in your case, if you don't issue a new query after 1 minute, then the search context will be automatically closed.

Comment: Ok. Open contexts are going up and down that means search context is being closed.

Comment: then it means need to keep track of IDs.

Comment: Exactly, the number of open context might increase during a certain time, but always decreases as there's always a default time out after which contexts are closed automatically. If you set the timeout too high, though, you might run the risk of having too many contexts open. It's a good practice to keep track of open context IDs and close them explicitly when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Great thanks for the input. I am keeping this question open for few more days for any other thoughts otherwise will mark as accepted.

Comment: Nope. Nothing till now.

Comment: For now keeping tracks of open ids and then closing manually after a certain period of time.

Comment: "after a certain period of time"... why not providing a `keep_alive` value for that "period of time" so that they are closed automatically by ES?